# In VB.Net 2010 How Can I Set Default Value For Aall DataSet Table Columns On The Form Load?

Tags: vb.net, dataset, vb.net-2010

I have created a typed datasource and has null default value for just about every field.
I am not allowed to change the source tables themeslves.

I have created a datagrid by dragging the dataset table on to a form.
If a user tries to insert a new row and leaves a field without a value, the null is used which the data source table doesn't accept.

I'd therefore like to read through the dataset table columns and set the DefaultValue to 0 for numeric fields and blank for string fields.

I almost have it with the code below but it only sets the first column.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, 
                       ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'DataSet1.MyTable' table. 
    'You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.MyTableTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DataSet1.MyTable)

    For Each DataColumn In DataSet1.MyTable.Columns
        If DataColumn.DataType = Data.DbType.Decimal Then
            DataSet1.MyTable.Columns.Item(DataColumn).DefaultValue = 0
        Else
            DataSet1.MyTable.Columns.Item(DataColumn).DefaultValue = " "
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Try going through `DataSet1.MyTable.Rows` instead of it's columns and setting the Rows.Item(Index).DefaultValue

Comment: Looking at my code I think i should have put the dataColumn loop before the Me.MyTableAdapter.Fill as it gives the wrong impression of what i am trying to do.   I want to set the dataset default values before any data is loaded into the dataset table so the characteristics of the source table to not allow nulls for datagrid inserts is over-ridden by a default value.